# run custom init: Failed to spawn homepage main process: unable to execute: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, init, startupscript

I'm getting an error on my ubuntu 14.04 box, when I run my custom init script in `/etc/init/homepage.conf`

I'm trying to run it via:

```
sudo start homepage
```

I keep getting:

```
start: Job failed to start
```

in the logs under `/var/log/syslog`:

```
init: Failed to spawn homepage main process: unable to execute: No such file or directory
```

I tried researching it, but cannot seem to pinpoint why this is happening.

**`homepage.conf` contains:**

```
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

#setuid user
setuid homepage
setgid www-data

env PATH=/home/myuser/venv/bin
chdir /home/jd/venv
exec uwsgi --ini home.ini
```

**home.ini contains:**

```
module = wsgi_prod
master=true
processes=5
socket = homepage.sock
chmod-socket = 660
vacuum = true
```

die-on-term = true

The permissions for under: /home/myuser/venv are:

```
 [user]   [group]
homepage:homepage
```

Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: any luck on this?  I'm having the same issue.  Thanks

Comment: @baselq, if you still have the issue, check out my answer! Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 2):

I struggled with the same problem for awhile, and finally found the issue: The file it can't find is `uwsgi`.  In your upstart conf file (homepage.conf for you), edit the following line:

```
exec uwsgi --ini home.ini
```

to be:

```
exec /usr/local/bin/uwsgi --ini home.ini
```

or whatever the path to your local uwsgi is.  You can figure out the path by running `which uwsgi`.